# How to mark as done but keep resnooze until particular date in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

[image]

**Steps to reproduce the above example screenshot:**

1. Snooze a conversation
2. This will make the conversation disappear from your inbox
3. Let us assume the other person responds to this conversation while it was snoozed
4. The conversation will thus be pulled back into your inbox with the note `Resnooze`

**My question to the community:**

In *Inbox by Gmail*, how can I move such an email conversation out of my inbox again while preserving the `Resnooze Until` setting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Inbox by Gmail recently disabled the RESNOOZE feature.  I am incredibly frustrated by this, because your exact scenario was one that I experience frequently.  When the feature was available, you could simply click the RESNOOZE banner and it would move the thread out of your inbox until the next reply or the snooze date/time.  However, that this point it appears that each reply strips away your original snooze details.

If you're also frustrated by this, please send the development team feedback requesting them to re-enable the RESNOOZE feature.  You can find the options to send feedback at the bottom of the left menu in Inbox.

[image: Click Help & Feedback]

[image: Click Send feedback]